# BufferedWriter not Printing properly?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that creates a log of grades in a specified number of classes and writes this data to a text file. It writes the date, class names, grades (or at least it should), and a closing statement. For some reason I can't figure out, my program only prints out the date and class name. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
        BufferedWriter data = null; //Writes Output

    try {

        File log = new File ("Grade.txt"); //Name of File
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (log, true); //Appends File
        data = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter); //Creates BufferedWriter
        Date date = new Date (); //Sets Date

               //Code here makes an array of class names 

            System.out.print ("Enter Assignment Name:  ");
                title = reader.nextLine ();
                data.write (title);
                data.newLine (); //Blank Line
                reader.nextLine (); //Consume Input
                System.out.print ("Enter Points Possible:  ");
                temp = reader.nextInt();

                if (temp < 0){

                    throw new ArithmeticException ("");

                }else{

                    poss += temp;
                    data.write(poss);

                }//Close If

                System.out.print ("Enter Points Earned");
                temp = reader.nextInt();

                if (temp < 0){

                    throw new ArithmeticException ("");

                }else{

                    earn += temp;
                    data.write(earn);

                }//Close If
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't `.close()` the writer or the file before your program ends.  If you don't close the writer then you are not guaranteed that its internal buffers are flushed to the file and to the disk.

If you are using Java7, then you can use the try-with-resources for convenient and correctness:

```
try ( FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (log, true); //Appends File
      BuferredWriter data = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter); //Creates BufferedWriter
    )
    {
    data.write("...");
    }
```

Comment: Not closing it just consumes system resources, it shouldn't cause problems with writing to a file.

Comment: Perhaps, but Java does not guarantee that an object's finalizer will ever be called.  If the writer's finalizer is not called then it wouldn't necessarily flush its buffer.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that you shouldn't `close()` the stream, but that is not the cause of the OP's problems.

Answer (score 0):

Move the reader to the next line after reading the points. When using reader.nextInt the input only reads the number and not the new line character created when you press enter. Calling reader.nextLine after reader.nextInt reads the new line character and clears the buffer.

```
BufferedWriter data = null; //Writes Output

try {

    File log = new File ("Grade.txt"); //Name of File
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (log, true); //Appends File
    data = new BufferedWriter (fileWriter); //Creates BufferedWriter
    Date date = new Date (); //Sets Date

           //Code here makes an array of class names 

        System.out.print ("Enter Assignment Name:  ");
            title = reader.nextLine ();
            data.write (title);
            data.newLine (); //Blank Line
            reader.nextLine (); //Consume Input
            System.out.print ("Enter Points Possible:  ");
            temp = reader.nextInt();
            reader.nextLine(); //added this

            if (temp < 0){

                throw new ArithmeticException ("");

            }else{

                poss += temp;
                data.write(poss);

            }//Close If

            System.out.print ("Enter Points Earned");
            temp = reader.nextInt();
            reader.nextLine(); //added this

            if (temp < 0){

                throw new ArithmeticException ("");

            }else{

                earn += temp;
                data.write(earn);

            }//Close If
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nextInt()` method leaves the `\n` (end line) symbol and is picked up immediately by `nextLine()`, skipping over the next input.  What you want to do is use `nextLine()` for everything, and parse it later:

```
String nextIntString = keyboard.nextLine(); //get the number as a single line
int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString); //convert the string to an int
```

This is by far the easiest way to avoid problems--don't mix your "next" methods.  Use only `nextLine()` and then parse `int`s or separate words afterwards.

Also, you should always `close()` your `BufferedWriter` when you are done with it to conserve system resources.